# Django test project TemplateDoesNotExist at /

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I know this question has been asked many times but even after resolving all the things I am still getting this error. My setup is as follow -

> settings.py

```
    """
Django settings for my_notebook project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
#outside src folder
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'zzyo5*=sv3of&2la@$v=6)9x&+sn_b4sr94==mi1$b*&qhej+!'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (    
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'signups'
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'my_notebook.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'my_notebook.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

#templates location
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_1", "templates"),
)
```

as its appearing in the error page.
I have a file defined in this folder signup.html

My view appears as -

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response, RequestContext

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render_to_response("signup.html", locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

this view appears inside an app named signups which has been added to settings.py already in my project as -

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'signups'
)
```

Lastly urls.py of my project -

```
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', "signups.views.home", name='home'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Can someone please help me why i am getting this error

> TemplateDoesNotExist at / signup.html

I am using django 1.8.3.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please include your whole configuration. It seems, you have not configured `TEMPLATES` properly.

Comment: placed whole settings.py

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `TEMPLATE_DIRS` setting should only be configured if you are loading templates that do not belong to any application.

In your case you have a template `signup.html` that is for the `signups` application; so you should do this:

1. First, get rid of the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` setting. In django 1.8 this setting was removed anyway (see [this page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/upgrading/) on the new template configuration).
2. Create a directory called `templates` in the same directory that has the `views.py` for your signups app, it should look like this:

   ```
   signups/
      migrations/
      __init__.py
      admin.py
      models.py
      tests.py
      views.py
      templates/
          signups/
   ```
3. In this `signups/templates/signups/` directory, create your `signup.html` file.
4. Now, in your view you need:

   ```
   from django.shortcuts import render

   def home(request):
       return render(request, 'signups/signup.html')
   ```

Comment: Oh great, I am following an older version tutorial(1.6), Thanks for the help

Comment: You should always follow the [official tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/) and keep an eye on the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.8.3/) which detail changes on each version release.

Comment: @codeomnitrix My edit to BurhanKhalid's excellent answer got approved, make sure to check [Django's tutorial on reusable apps](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/reusable-apps/) for further explanation.